# Specialisations of class template members

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a header containing a class with a template member and some specialisations of that member:

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void print(const T& t) {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
void Foo::print<int>(const int& t) {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

This header is included in multiple source files.

If I put the specialisation inside the class definition, then GCC complains:

```
error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class Foo’
```

But if I move the specialisation outside the class definition, then VC++ complains about multiply-defined symbols.

What's the right way of doing this that both compilers will be happy with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An explicitly specialized template function is no longer a template (it no longer depends on any template parameters). As such it obeys the One Definition Rule as an ordinary function. This means that the *definition* of an explicitly specialized function should be made once and only once in the entire program. I.e. you have to place the definition into an implementation file (`.cpp` file).

However, you still have to *declare* this specialization in the header file (to tell the compiler that it actually exists). I.e. in the header file you have to do

```
template<> 
void Foo::print<int>(const int& t);
```

(Note that per standard requirements it should be done in namespace scope, i.e. outside of the class definition.)

Then in one implementation file you do

```
template<>
void Foo::print<int>(const int& t) {
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

P.S. Of course, just as with any other function, you can declare it `inline` and keep the definition in the header file.

Comment: Hmmm, fair enough, I guess. But if it's just an ordinary member function, then why doesn't G++ let you declare it inside the class?

Comment: @Tom Because explicit specializations of member functions have to be in namespace-scope, whether they're members or not.

Comment: @Tom: Short answer: because the language standard says so. Explicit specializations have to be declared in namespace scope. Long answer: I don't know the rationale behind this. I myself always wondered why *partial* specializations are allowed in class scope, but *explicit* specializations are not.

Answer (score 0):

The standard says (§14.7.3/12):

> An explicit specialization of a function template is inline only if it
>   is declared with the inline specifier or defined as deleted, and
>   independently of whether its function template is inline.

A specialization of a function template is treated by the ODR like a normal function (no specialization).
If you define the specialization inside the header, you have to declare it with the `inline` specifier, so several translation units can include it.

If you want to define it in the source file, you have to declare the specialization inside the  header (at namespace scope):

```
template<>
void Foo::print<int>(const int&);
```

And put the definition in the source file

```
template<>
void Foo::print<int>(const int& t)
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

, just as you're used to with normal functions.